# Cannot allow access www-data user and group to external hard drive

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, mount

I am trying to place a uploads folder on an external hard drive. When I run the commands below I still get access denied for www-data.I even chmod 777 the folder. Any Suggestions? I am using Ubuntu 15.04

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /mnt/d7c4f23-9bcf/uploads
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Apart form giving permissions on /mnt/d7c4f23-9bcf/uploads to www-data.

You need to make sure that /mnt and /mnt/d7c4f23-9bcf has atleast read permissions for www-data or for all.

Comment: I did chmod 777 the whole folder, is that enough to get permissions?

Comment: No. You need atleast read permission on the parent directories.  One way is chmod o+r  /mnt/d7c4f23-9bcf && chmod o+r  /mnt